# How to resolve Jenkins status : Active (exited)?

Tags: jenkins, service, centos7, status, systemctl

I checked Memory capacity,swap capacity, restart service, upgrade jenkins, permission directories 
But jenkins status is "Active(exited)" and couldn't access to application.
How can i resolve this issue?
(OS: CentOS 7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of a version conflict of installed Jenkins. You probably upgraded the version of Jenkins by just copying .war file into /usr/lib/jenkins/ path.

You may solve the problem via installing the required version using the following example command:

```
    rpm -Uvh jenkins-2.138.2-1.1.noarch.rpm
```